# Error in Spyder: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32file'

Tags: python, spyder

Every time I run simulations I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32file'.
```

I've tried:

```
pip install pywin32
pip install pywin32==223
pip install pywin32
pip install pypiwin32
```

But nothing seems to work, pywin32 is already installed. I get:

```
pip install win32file

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32file (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32file
```